# during update query it throws NotSupportedException?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8

I am dealing with SQLite in windows store application.I am updating the values in table using

```
var tagPage = db.QueryAsync<MyModel>("UPDATE MyModel SET Tag =2 WHERE id = 1");
db.UpdateAsync(tagPage);
```

It throws an NotSupportedException on SQLite.cs class over the method

```
public int Update(object obj, Type objType)
{
    if (obj == null || objType == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        var map = GetMapping(objType);

        var pk = map.PK;

        if (pk == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot update " + map.TableName + ": it has no PK");
        }

        var cols = from p in map.Columns
                   where p != pk
                   select p;
        var vals = from c in cols
                   select c.GetValue(obj);
        var ps = new List<object>(vals);
        ps.Add(pk.GetValue(obj));
        var q = string.Format("update \"{0}\" set {1} where {2} = ? ", map.TableName, string.Join(",", (from c in cols
                                                                                                        select "\"" + c.Name + "\" = ? ").ToArray()), pk.Name);
        return Execute(q, ps.ToArray());
}
```

because I think it wont get the primery key, where I have provided primery key in table.
I tried  it with async and await but no use, why it is happening? please help me

Comment: Can you add database schema?

Comment: how exactly we do so? is it mean to add our own method to update values in SQLite.cs?
I used var conn = new SQLiteConnection("path") and then conn.update("Query").Yes it throws exception but after updating db, so if I catch exception it works fine for me.I know its not a good way to do so, can you suggest me valid method to do so.

Comment: Hard to diagnose what is happening without knowing how the database is made. Can you put the database schema into your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your `NotSupportedException` issue - I suspect that your model is missing the `PrimaryKey` attribute:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Tag { get; set; }        
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

You will need the attribute(s) above, even if your db schema already has them defined. At this time, Sqlite-Net does not read schema data from the db.

Some other thoughts:

Firstly, you should use only either the synchronous Sqlite-Net API, or the async API. Don't use both.

I personally prefer the synchronous API, as it appears to be more up to date. The async API has not been updated in 11 months, whereas the synchronous API was updated 4 months ago. Besides this I never was able to figure out how to do transactions using the async API. Again, this is personal preference.

Secondly, the `Query` and `QueryAsync` methods should be used only for querying (for `SELECT`s). They should not be used for `UPDATE`s. For adding/changing data, you will want to use these synchronous methods: `Execute`, `Update`, `Insert`, etc.  If using the async API, there are the  async counterparts (`ExecuteAsync`, etc).

Please read the [Sqlite-Net Project page](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), as you will find a lot of helpful information there regarding general API usage.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have already implemented  [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement] in my model.I'll try it as you suggested using synchronously